Using grep to print distinct list of matches
I want to search my codebase for anything which matches a particular pattern, but I only want to see the distinct set of strings which match the pattern, without context or filenames.
For example:
$ echo 'foo\nfoo\nfoo\nFoo\nboo' | grep --ignore-case '[fb]oo'
foo
Foo
boo


Since posting this Q&A I've discovered this answer on superuser which has a slightly less searchable title.

If awk is an option, this can be accomplished with awk '/[fb]oo/i {a[$0]} END {for (i in a) print i}

@pmf: what's /i part doing here? Is it GNU extension for case insensitive? BTW, you're missing final '.

or maybe it's equivalent to '/[fb]oo/ i to always take a line but in that case it works only in this specific example, if the string was it would also print 123.

I mean if the string was 'foo\nfoo\nfoo\nFoo\nboo\n123'.

echo 'foo\nfoo\nfoo\nFoo\nboo' is likely to output foo\nfoo\nfoo\nFoo\nboo; try printf 'foo\nfoo\nfoo\nFoo\nboo\n' (remember to add a newline at the end!) or echo $'foo\nfoo\nfoo\nFoo\nboo'. Details matter. :)

You can get grep to only give you the matches, with no context, like this:
grep --only-matching --no-filename <pattern>

If you pipe this to or sort -u or uniq (after sorting first!) you'll get the output you're looking for:
$ echo 'foo\nfoo\nfoo\nFoo\nboo' \
  | grep --ignore-case --only-matching --no-filename '[fb]oo' \
  | sort -u
Foo
boo
foo


Note that this is not specific to ripgrep, and works with grep just the same. Also, sort | uniq can be shortened to just sort -u.

tl;dr
If order doesn't matter, sort -u is simple and easy.
$: grep -hori '[bf]oo' * | sort -u
Boo
Foo
boo
foo

If you want your order preserved, use awk.
$: grep -hori '[bf]oo' * | awk '{ if(seen[$0]++) next; print }'
foo
Boo
Foo
boo


Breaking It Out
As LondonRob and pmf said, piping to sort -u is a reasonably quick and easy solution - as long as order doesn't matter. It will, however, likely reorder your data. If that does matter, or if you want output ASAP in one pass over the data, awk is better.
pmf also offered an awk solution in a comment, but which again makes you wait till all the data is received and processed before beginning to give output, and will almost certainly reorder it. It also does not strip context the way grep -o does, and /i to make matches case-insensitive isn't really a standard awk thing.
If you want every new & unique record as soon as seen, and in the order they occur (this version without context stripping for simplicity) -
$: awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} /[bf]oo/{ if(seen[$0]++) next; print }' *
foo
foobar
bazfoo
fooBoobarBooFoofoo
Foo
Boo
boo

This doesn't report filenames, as requested. It uses IGNORECASE. That's a GNU thing, though, I think.
Note that for very large datasets this could use a lot of memory; only for lines that meet your search pattern, but it does hold the whole line.
(sort is optimized for that, at least.)
It does generate context which the OP asked not to get.
This version does not.
$: cat foos
foo
foobar
123
bazfoo
fooBoobarBooFoofoo # uh-oh, this line is being ignored!
Foo
foo
Boo
boo

$: awk -v IGNORECASE=1 '/[bf]oo/{ if(seen[gensub(/.*([bf]oo).*/,"\\1",1)]++) next; print }' * # oops! out of order!
foo
Foo
Boo
boo

I used -v to set IGNORECASE here to save a few bytes and show another approach, but it's effectively the same. If you need a non-GNU specific version:
$: awk 'tolower($0)~/[bf]oo/{ if(seen[gensub(/.*([BbFf]oo).*/,"\\1",1)]++) next; print }' * # same issue
foo
Foo
Boo
boo

That complicates your pattern a little, but it's not too bad.
Unfortunately there's also the flaw that (as is) it can miss lines with more than one hit on your pattern match. (Look at the order they come out, it's wrong.)
To make awk handle that is entirely possible (see below), but now you are getting into more complex programming, and maybe all you wanted was just to get your damned data without all that work...
While I usually (pretty strongly) advocate against using multiple pattern matching tools in a pipeline when it can be avoided, this might be a case where giving each the parts they are good at makes sense. grep can't remember whether it has already seen a pattern, but it's great at splitting them up and keeping them in order for you, while awk makes it easy to track whether or not you've seen one before and skip if it has.
$: grep -io '[bf]oo' * | awk '{ if(seen[$0]++) next; print }'
foo
Boo
Foo
boo

Note the order change. It's correct now, but we're back to filenames if there are multiple hits:
$: grep -io '[bf]oo' * | awk '{ if(seen[$0]++) next; print }'
foo2:foo
foos:foo
foos:Boo
foos:Foo
foos:boo

But that's ok, we can tell grep not to give us filenames, even if we want to scan recursive directories and files.
$: grep -roi '[bf]oo' * | awk '{ if(seen[$0]++) next; print }'
bar/foo3:foo
foo2:foo
foos:foo
foos:Boo
foos:Foo
foos:boo

$: grep -hori '[bf]oo' * | awk '{ if(seen[$0]++) next; print }'
foo
Boo
Foo
boo

In the end we still end up running only 2 programs, and still get unique occurrences, even counting multiple hits on one line, but with order preserved.
If you just wanted to have awk do it all in one process, though, you can.
$: find
.
./bar
./bar/foo3
./foo2
./foos

$: find -type f
./bar/foo3
./foo2
./foos

$: mapfile -td $'\0' l < <( find -type f -print0 ) # list my files
$: awk '{ split($0, trash, "[FfBb]oo", hits); for (i in hits) if (!seen[hits[i]]++) print hits[i] }' "${l[@]}"
foo
Boo
Foo
boo

That awk broken out a little easier to read:
$: awk '{
 split($0, trash, "[FfBb]oo", hits); # split on pattern
   for (i in hits)                     # PATTERN went in hits
     if (!seen[hits[i]]++)             # first time for each
       print hits[i]                   # show the split pattern
}                                      # seen[] remembered
' "${l[@]}"
foo
Boo
Foo
boo


This doesn't address I/O buffering; see here for the GNU page related to that, but it basically says you might need to fflush (or use system("")) to force that.
